# docx4j works fine inside Eclipse but throws error anywhere else

Tags: eclipse, jaxb, moxy, docx4j

I've started using docx4j a little while ago and I found this situation that is causing me some issues.
I created a class that works like a charm in Eclipse but when I try to run it as a standalone in another server I get: Couldn't get [Content_Types].xml from ZipFile.

I read some posts on this that suggest this is related to JAXB and advised to switch to MOXy but the instructions I found are for Maven and I can't use Maven here (not my choice, I'm restricted).

As such, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The relevant part of the trace goes like this:

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Couldn't get [Content_Types].xml from ZipFile
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.get(Load3.java:136)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:462)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:379)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:270)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:250)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:168)
at testFile.createTestFile(testFile.java:107)
...Caused by: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Bad [Content_Types].xml
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:759)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.get(Load3.java:134)
```

I'm opening the file like this:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(loader.getResource("testFile.docx").getPath()));
```

The docx file is located in the same folder of the class file.

TIA!

Comment: Which Java?  What jars do you have on your class path?  You could try just http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/archive/docx4j-3.3.1-beta-shaded.jar

Comment: Using Java 1.6. In my class path I have the docx4j-3.3.1 and all dependencies. As for the jar you suggested, tried just now with same results.

Comment: So what is the difference between your Eclipse environment, and your standalone environment? I guess you have an input docx ... how are you opening it?  Post the full stack trace please

Comment: I'm running the class file in a Adobe Coldfusion 10 Java application server for which I have limited view on configuration (again, not my choice, just riding with the flow). I've updated my initial post with some more information.

Comment: Please verify testFile.docx does in fact contain  [Content_Types].xml, by unzipping it.  You might also configure logging for more clues.